# Image in showcase view

Tags: android, image, showcaseview

I am using showcase view in my android app to give the users a tutorial of my app. Everything is working fine but the image displayed on screen is a circle like in the link-'https://www.novoda.com/blog/showcaseview-customisation-and-having-consecutive-showcases/'. I want to change it to a finger of the hand pointing to things like shown in-'http://images.pcworld.com/images/article/2012/07/screenshot_2012-07-02-13-27-42-11381455.png'. I have the Image in my drawable folder but I don't know how to use it. Any help??